# Is there more than 1 cluster in 1D data serie?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science

Serie of values might, or might not have clusters. In example:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 21, 22]
```

has [21, 22] falling into a second cluster.

What unsupervised method allows for telling if there is more than 1 cluster in data without manually setting any threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clusters are somewhat abstract definition, getting it's meaning from the data and context, in your sequence there can be 1 or multiple clusters, depends on what algo you used and how many clusters did you ask it to find

you can use methods to evaluate the output clustering and by this deduce the optimal number of clusters
most methods works by compare the similarity between points in the same cluster and in different clusters

I suggest you read the following
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)

Comment: Thank you! Will read.   My intuition is that a cluster in my case is such a subset that the sigma within its members is less than a blank between its members and the other cluster memebers.

Comment: Indeed, the Elbow method seems to be the solution. Trying and evaluating various number of clusters makes sense!